# How can we describe the level curves?

Tags: calculus, curves

Using polar coordinates, I have to describe the level curves of the function:

$$ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x, y) \rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} & \text{ if } (x, y) \neq (0,0)\\ 
0 & \text{ if } (x, y)=(0, 0)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I have done the following:

$x=r \cos \theta , y=r \sin \theta$

If $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$ then: 
$$\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} =\frac{2r \cos \theta r \sin \theta}{r^2 \cos^2 \theta+r^2 \sin^2 \theta} =\frac{2r^2 \cos \theta  \sin \theta}{r^2}=2 \cos \theta  \sin \theta=\sin 2 \theta$$

How can we describe the level curves??

Answer (score 1):

The level curves of $f$ are the curves $f=constant$.  In this case, $\sin2\theta=constant$.  We can call the constant $\sin2\alpha$, where $-\frac12\pi\le2\alpha\le\frac12\pi$, and solving the equation
$$\sin2\theta=\sin2\alpha$$
gives the level curves
$$\theta=\alpha\ \hbox{or}\ \frac\pi2-\alpha$$
for $-\frac14\pi\le\alpha\le\frac14\pi$.

Comment: How did you find the contraints for $a$??  So does the level set consist of the points $\theta=a$, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-a$ ??

Comment: Since $\sin2\theta$ must be between $-1$ and $1$, all possible values can be written as sine of something.  Calling it $\sin2\alpha$ makes solving for $\theta$ easier.  Taking $2\alpha$ from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ gives $\sin2\alpha$ all possible values from $-1$ to $1$.  Note that $\theta=\alpha$ is not a point, it is a curve (actually a straight line).

Comment: OK... Could you explain to me why $\theta=a$ is a curve and especially a straight line??

Comment: Have you learnt about polar coordinates?